# my page scrolls to the bottom on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome

once my page is loaded, it jumps to the bottom of the page. that only happens in Chrome. what would cause that?. I have some JavaScript run on page load. it initializes google maps.

here is my page link: http://al-bawabeh.com/add.php

Comment: How about posting your source code, and a link to your page....

Comment: It might help if you add a bunch of white space to the bottom (e.g. <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>) in order to see _precisely_ where it scrolls to.