# why does my page scroll to the bottom when is loaded and google maps is being loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-maps-api-3

once my page is loaded, google maps is being loaded and my page scrolls to the botton and refuse to scroll up till G.map is loaded. that only happens in Chrome. here is my page http://al-bawabeh.com/add.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [my page scrolls to the bottom on Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695090/my-page-scrolls-to-the-bottom-on-chrome)

Comment: I posted that and I waited and waited and waited for a proper answer but none solved it.

Comment: You didn't react on the last comment  there, I think it's first up to you to do anything (except of duplicating the question)